# Foreign keys with Sequelize and Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js

Given these 2 Sequelize models:

```
export class Users extends Model<Users> {

    @HasMany(() => UserRoles)
    @Column({ primaryKey: true, allowNull: false, unique: true })
    UserId: string;

    @Column({ allowNull: false, unique: true })
    Email: string;
}

export class UserRoles extends Model<UserRoles> {

    @ForeignKey(() => Users)
    @Column({ primaryKey: true, allowNull: false, unique: true })
    UserId: string;

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    RoleId: number;
}
```

When I create a user I will also create a row in `UserRoles` with the `UserId` being the foreign key and so there is always a One to one match.

When I try to run this I get:

`Error: Naming collision between attribute 'UserId' and association 'UserId' on model Users. To remedy this, change either foreignKey or as in your association definition`

I imagine that means that the 2 tables have the same column name `UserId` and that is causing the problem?
If so how can I fix that? give it some kind of alias? or how?

Comment: You've specified that `UserRolls.prototype.UserId` is a primary key. Seems like `UserRolls.prototype.RoleId` ought to be the primary key.

Comment: @AluanHaddad But in my table `UserRoles` the only column that is unique is `UserId`, the `RoleId` is not unique (can be either `1` or `2`)

Answer (score 0):

if you want a one to one model i.e  **one user can only be assigned one role and vice versa** then use same field for both primary and foreign key constraints otherwise use different one